# Картинка вместо фона. Прыгает фон

Tags: css3, facebook, html5

Доброго времени суток.
Вот решил сделать картинку в место фона. Чтобы при прокрутке страницы вниз картинка оставалась на месте.
Когда вызываю модального окно fancybox, то при открытии и закрытии окна прыгает задний фон.

Вот сам html:

```
  <?if(!empty($arResult["USER"]["UF_IMAGES_GROUND"])):?>
    <style>
        .myBgFon{
            background: url("<?=$arResult["USER"]["UFIMAGES_GROUND_RESIZE"]["src"]?>") 100% 100%;
            background-size: cover;
        }
    </style>
<?endif;?>
 <div class="main_container_cabinet">
<div class="bl_bg_cabinet_user<?=(!empty($arResult["USER"]["UF_IMAGES_GROUND"]) ? " myBgFon" : " noPicUser")?>"></div>
<div class="bl_bg_default_cabinet_user"></div>
<div class="bl_content_cabinet_user"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
 .main_container_cabinet{
min-height: 100%;
position: relative;
}
.main_container_cabinet .bl_bg_cabinet_user,
.main_container_cabinet .bl_bg_default_cabinet_user{
height: 100%;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
}
.main_container_cabinet .bl_bg_cabinet_user{
z-index: -3;
 }

.main_container_cabinet .bl_bg_default_cabinet_user{
z-index: -1;
opacity: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
 }
.main_container_cabinet .bl_content_cabinet_user{
 }
```

Comment: Посмотрите также background-size и background-position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не совсем понятно без примера. Но все же...

Фон может "прыгать" из-за того, что фансибокс при открытии добавляет к тегам `html` и `body` класс с `overflow:hidden`, чтобы утрать скорлл.

Может, это поможет:

```
$('#block').fancybox({
  helpers: {
    overlay: {
      locked: false
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, это как раз то, что нужно.